# replace the logical operator in mysql where clause

Tags: mysql

what if i want to change the logical operator AND,OR on some condition in a where clause of select query.

for e.g

```
select * from table t where t.column='something' AND t.column='something'

select * from table t where t.column='something' OR t.column='something'
```

What i tried:

```
select * from table t where t.column='something' 
case some_variable 
when  some_variable='' THEN OR
ELSE AND
END
t.column='something'
```

but it throws a syntax error near case clause.
Please advise.

EDIT:
Sample fiddle [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mzvqtwcswzREhzdg4ReoXi/0)

Comment: Why two conditions same?

Comment: What you are thying can does not work

Comment: actually the conditions are approx same for the result i want to achieve but i need to change the logical operator

Comment: But i guess if you add sample data and desired result, then it's easy to find alternative and easy solution for your problem.

Comment: The logic doesn't work-  t.column='something' AND t.column='something'  can never evaluate to true, and no you cannot generate dynamic code this way.

Comment: @Harshil i tried but dosen't worked for me. i will link the fiddle in short

Comment: @P.Salmon my bad didn't noticed it. the other column is from different table and the query has a join

Comment: Fiddle will be really helpful

Comment: please check @Harshil [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mzvqtwcswzREhzdg4ReoXi/0)

Comment: Ok. Lemme check

Comment: Ok. There are lots of conditions in Where clause. Which one you want to change and what is the end result you want?

Comment: Are you trying to only select on empid if that is what is passed or only select on status if '' or a value is passed?

Comment: @P.Salmon what i want is that when the car_status parameter is empty the record in car_detail table having status 'reserved' and 'active' should get selected. means on behalf of emp_id i want to get all the rows having status active and reserved and (the status having sold and sure but only the record of specific employee) from car_detail table. Second if the car_status parameter is passed(sold,sure,reserved) only the record of that specific employee from car_detail having status sold,sure,reserved

Comment: the sample query is working in the scenerio when the car_status is not passed but when it is passed i need to change the OR to AND just like this: `(car_status='' AND (car_detail.status='active' OR car_detail.status='reserved') 
 OR car_detail.status = car_status)` **AND** `car_reservation_detail.employee_detail_id=emp_id AND car_reservation_detail.status='active';`

Comment: which column represents  employee_detail_id in car_detail table?

Comment: Is this the solution? : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n2SNSoZ7pPp1hR7QaumFJi/0      Note: I've changed one `car_detail_id` from `1` to `2` in 2nd row of `car_reservation_detail` table

Comment: @Harshil employee_detail_id is only present in car_reservation detail

Comment: Yes I got that. Please check the link from my prev comment and tell whether it's giving the desired result?

Comment: @Harshil its working for the second condition if i pass a car_status and it gives all the record of that employee depending upon the parameter passed however if i don't pass it it's only showing the active and reserved record whereas it should show the sure sold records of that employee as well

Comment: Ok. I'LL add that part.

Comment: done: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kqtERvrZEJjNjp6QGyU8eb/0

Comment: @Harshil thanks mate

Comment: i guess it worked then. I'll add it as answer.

Comment: yes it does @Harshil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following has worked successfully.

```
select
DISTINCT

`car_detail`.`car_detail_id` as "Car ID.",
`car_detail`.`status` as "Status"

FROM 
`car_detail`

LEFT JOIN `car_reservation_detail` ON car_reservation_detail.car_detail_id=car_detail.car_detail_id


WHERE
(case when car_status='' then (car_detail.status='active' OR car_detail.status='reserved') OR (`car_reservation_detail`.employee_detail_id = emp_id AND     (`car_detail`.`status` = 'sold' or `car_detail`.`status` = 'sure'))
 else 
  (`car_reservation_detail`.employee_detail_id = emp_id AND     `car_detail`.`status` = car_status AND `car_reservation_detail`.`status`='active')
 end)
;
```

[DBfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kqtERvrZEJjNjp6QGyU8eb/0)